# AngularJS 2 a Promise resolve loses class identity upon feching

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular-promise

SUMMARY:
I supposedly fetch some Org objects which have class methods.  But when I fetch my data I'm seeing Object instances, not Org instances.  Is this the best available result?  Or can I convince my program to give me Org objects?

DETAILS:
I'm working with a recent version of Angular 2.  My code slightly modifies some tutorial code.  Here is part of my org.service.ts:

```
getOrgs(): Promise<Org[]> {
  return this.http
    .get(this.orgUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().data as Org[])
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

getOrg(id: number): Promise<Org> {
  return this.getOrgs()
    .then((orgs: Org[]) : Org => orgs.find(org => org.id === id));
}
```

Here is part of my resolver:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<Org>|boolean {
  let id = this.authService.user.orgId;

  return this.orgService.getOrg(id).then((org: Org) : Org|boolean => {

    if(org) { // <-- Breakpoint here
      return org;
    } else { 
      // If  the Org isn't available then the edit page isn't appropriate.
      this.router.navigate(['/provider/home']);
      return false;
    }

  });
}
```

I'm fetching my data through an in-memory service:

```
export class InMemoryDataService {

  createDb() {
    let org1 = new Org();
    org1.id = 12;
    org1.donor = true;
    org1.name = 'Great Actors Theater';
    let org2 = new Org();
    org2.id = 19;
    org2.donor = false;
    org2.name = 'Sunnyside Group Home';
    let org: Org[] = [];
    org.push(org1);
    org.push(org2);
[SNIP]
```

And my Org class is like this:

```
export class Org {
  id: number;
  donor: boolean;
  name: string = "";

  deepCopy(): Org { ... }

  equals(other: Org): boolean { ... }
}
```

When I look at my data at the breakpoint I see an object that has the fields (id, donor, name) but no functions.  I also don't see a definition of Org there -- if I call "org instanceof Org" I get an error that Org can't be found.  And "typeof org" yields "object".

I wish to have equals(), etc, as an Org class method.  But at present I have only Javascript objects that are *like* Org only by duck-typing.  Can I get better out of it?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the `Org` instance from the JSON.

Something like:

```
.then(response => {
   // validate response
   return response.json().data.map(d => new Org(d))
})
```

Then define how to construct an `Org` instance in the class declaration e.g:

```
export class Org {
  id: number;
  donor: boolean;
  name: string = "";

  constructor(data: any) {
     // validate data
     this.id = data.id;
     this.donor = data.donor;
     this.name = data.name;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is working for me.  In terms of my example above the getOrgs().then() changes to be .then(response => response.json().data.map((d: any) => new Org(d)) as Org[]).  Thank you so much!